# How big were the Nine Realms of Norse mythology?

Tags: norse, world-tree

Is it mentioned anywhere in the scriptures how big the ancient Norse believed the Nine Realms of their myths were?

Comment: Mass or Size? Cuz big is am*big*ous

Comment: @bleh well, i was kinda looking size.somewhat like if each realm is a planet or land or something else.

Comment: @bleh like how to classify them

Comment: Aren't 8/9 of the realms massless and imaginary? Only Midgard is solid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the realms as parts of the earth (as some scholars do) some realms were as big as today's Germany, some about the size of Denmark ([The Prose Edda, page 14](http://www.redicecreations.com/files/The-Prose-Edda.pdf)).

A more mythological answer would be the realms were not only different sizes but also wildly different in shape:

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to include an actual quote from the Prose Edda? linking to "page 14" of a pdf document is not very helpful. do you mean page 14 of the pdf, or page 14 of the original document?